# Linking OpenGL using MinGW on Windows x86_64

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, mingw-w64

I would like to develope an application using C++ and OpenGL for Windows 64bit. 
I am using the following Compiler `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++`.

The following code snippet (`Test.cpp`) is sufficient to trigger the error I get:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>

int main(int argn, char **argv) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

(I know this code is meaningless, but it is sufficient to trigger the error during linking.)

I use the following Makefile:

```
Test:
    g++ -lopengl32 -o Test Test.cpp
```

This yields the following error:

```
undefined reference to `__imp_glClear'
```

I have no clue what I am missing, and would be very thankfull for any advice.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the calling convention is correct. It should be `__imp__glClear@4` (effectively **__stdcall** in MSVC).

Comment: Can you try adding `-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup` to your `g++` command line? Also, I'm pretty sure `-lopengl32` should be on the other side of your argument list (should come last).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I tried 'g++ -o Test Test.cpp -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup -lopengl32' and it worked for my example 'Text.cpp', thank you very much for that. I have no clue what this additional argument does, but i really would like to lern about it. Could you explain to me, what the problem was and how it is solved by the additional argument?

Comment: That argument tells the linker to try and add the extra "decorations" that the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler adds to the end of functions that use the `__stdcall` calling convention. In this case, it is the `@4` (which means that it is a standard call function that is passed 4-bytes worth of function arguments on the stack). I'm not sure if that was the fix or simply moving `-lopengl32`, because the *stdcall-fixup* stuff is generally enabled by default.

Comment: Normally when compiling for the windows plattform you have to include `windows.h` before `GL/gl.h` to get the WINAPI macro that defines the calling convention. Did you do funny things with your OpenGL headers?

Answer (score 0):

For me the `g++ main.cpp -o run.exe -lopengl32` seems to work just fine, so you most likely wont need `-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup` to compile it.